# adMob rewarded video ad loading really slow

Tags: android, admob, ads, rewardedvideoad

My rewarded video is loading really really slow even for a video ad.
And sometimes it won't load at all.
My app:
I have a MainActivity (where I first init the MobileAd with my app ID).
And then you can go to the "get help" Activity where the rewarded video ad loads and you can watch it in exchange for clues.
I noticed that the video would load only once in the app lifetime. after that, and after go back to the main activity and then return to the "get help", the video won't load.

Like I said, the init of the mobile ads is in the onCreate() of the MainActivity.
in the GetHelpActivity there is an instance of RewardedVideoAd in the class and I am loading the ad in the onResume() of the class.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does it take so long for the video to load and why it will load only once in the application lifetime ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `loadAd()` to reload rewarded ad.
inside

```
RewardedVideoAd mAd;
     @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
   mAd.loadAd();
        }
```

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video-adapters

Comment: Like I said, the loadAd() function is found in the onResume of the GetHelp activity. The problem is once the ad was loaded in the entire application's lifetime, it won't load again. No matter how many times I will call the loadAd() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onRewardedVideoompleted.load` ad in `onRewardedVideoCompleted.onAdclosed` will be only called when ad is closed(when user click X).hope it helps